# Swift: override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) doesn't perform

Tags: swift, time

I am creating a game, in which random enemies are released and thrown towards the target, I am attempting to have a difficulty system, so the higher the score the greater the difficulty for example:

```
if score < 100{
            enemy.runAction(SKAction.moveTo(mainBall.position, duration:3))
        }
        else if score >= 100 && score < 200{
            enemy.runAction(SKAction.moveTo(mainBall.position, duration:2.5))

        }
        else if score >= 200 && score < 300{
            enemy.runAction(SKAction.moveTo(mainBall.position, duration:2))
        }
        else{
            enemy.runAction(SKAction.moveTo(mainBall.position, duration:1.5))
        }
```

So essentially the enemies move to the target faster. My problem is, I have all this code within the function for the enemies.

```
 func Enemies(){}
```

I want this difficulty code to be within the:

```
override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval)
```

so that it executes the code before every frame. However when I place this code within this function nothing works.

Here's some other code to consider:

```
func Enemies(){
        // Properties of the enemies
        let enemy = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Ball")
        enemy.size = CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)
        enemy.color = UIColor(red: 0.9, green: 0.1, blue: 0.1, alpha: 1.0)
        enemy.colorBlendFactor = 1.0
        // Physics
        enemy.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: enemy.size.width/2)
        enemy.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.enemy
        enemy.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.smallBall | PhysicsCatagory.mainBall
        enemy.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.smallBall | PhysicsCatagory.mainBall
        enemy.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        enemy.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        enemy.name = "enemy"

        let randomPosNmbr = arc4random() % 4

        switch randomPosNmbr{
        case 0:
            enemy.position.x = 0
            var positionY = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(frame.size.height))
            enemy.position.y = CGFloat(positionY)
            self.addChild(enemy)
        case 1:
            enemy.position.y = 0
            var positionX = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(frame.size.width))
            enemy.position.x = CGFloat(positionX)
            self.addChild(enemy)
        case 2:
            enemy.position.y = frame.size.height
            var positionX = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(frame.size.width))
            enemy.position.x = CGFloat(positionX)
            self.addChild(enemy)
        case 3:
            enemy.position.x = frame.size.width
            var positionY = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(frame.size.height))
            enemy.position.y = CGFloat(positionY)
            self.addChild(enemy)
        default:
            break
            }
        if score < 100{
            enemy.runAction(SKAction.moveTo(mainBall.position, duration:3))
        }
        else if score >= 100 && score < 200{
            enemy.runAction(SKAction.moveTo(mainBall.position, duration:2.5))
            if count < 1 {
                runAction(SKAction.colorizeWithColor(SKColor.purpleColor(), colorBlendFactor: 1.0, duration: 2.0))
                count++
            }
        }
        else if score >= 200 && score < 300{
            enemy.runAction(SKAction.moveTo(mainBall.position, duration:2))
        }
        else{
            enemy.runAction(SKAction.moveTo(mainBall.position, duration:1.5))
        }
```

and in the touchesBegan function:

```
enemyTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.7, target: self, selector:Selector("Enemies"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'nothing works'?

Comment: The enemies do not fly to the users object

Comment: The problem is, that you start the runAction everytime the update-method gets called. You have to change that.